# Selenium - How to open url in active/current tab in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
def get_status(driver):
    try:
        driver.execute(Command.STATUS)
        return "Alive"
    except (socket.error, httplib.CannotSendRequest):
        return "Dead"

    if get_status(driver) == 'Alive':
 #using this opens a whole new window but i want to go to another website in same tab.
           driver.get('https://www.amazon.in') 
    else :
            driver.get('https://www.google.in')
```

so basically i want to open a new url in the active tab of chrome/firefox browser. but i failed to find any workaround. i hope you can answer this question.

all tutorials on this redirect me to java function

```
driver.navigate.to()
```

which is not working in python.

Comment: What would happen if this gets executed successfully ? `driver.execute(Command.STATUS)` ? Also, what exactly do you mean by active tab ?

Comment: @Imran Syed - Are you calling `get_status(driver)` within `def get_status(driver):`?  After `except` ? `If` block wont be detected after `except`.

Answer (score 0):

This code did open a new URL within the same tab.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.command import Command
import http.client as httplib
import socket

def get_status(driver):
    try:
        driver.execute(Command.STATUS)
        return "Alive"
    except (socket.error, httplib.CannotSendRequest):
        return "Dead"


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path to chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")

if get_status(driver) == 'Alive':
    # using this opens a whole new window but i want to go to another website in same tab.
    driver.get('https://www.amazon.in')
else:
    driver.get('https://www.google.in')
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Can you add bit more context to your answer. As it's written it's hard to understand and read.